# How to read images and labels to batches in tensorflow from separate files with shared keys?

Tags: python, image, label, tensorflow

I am trying to use the convolutional network code on cifar-10 from the tensorflow tutorial with my own images (various sizes). Now the images and labels are stored separately with image names as keys. I was wondering how to modify the following function in cifar10_input.py. Thanks.

```
def read_cifar10(filename_queue):

  class CIFAR10Record(object):
    pass
  result = CIFAR10Record()

  label_bytes = 1  # 2 for CIFAR-100
  result.height = 32
  result.width = 32
  result.depth = 3
  image_bytes = result.height * result.width * result.depth

  record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes

  reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
  result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

  record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)

  result.label = tf.cast(
      tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)

  depth_major = tf.reshape(tf.slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes], [image_bytes]),
                           [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
  result.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])

  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FixedLengthRecordReader  it seemed that the reader.read op is reading the image and the label

result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

If you want to read in images of various sizes, i dont know if that works without reshaping, with the same network?? but i am tensorflow newbii, so it could be  possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I understand, the reader.read op reads in both the image and label if they are stores in the same file? In my case, I only have jpg pictures and a file storing labels, the names of the images work as keys. How can I input them in this case (no worries about the image size, I guess I can resize them later)?

Comment: you could read the jpeg with https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/image.html      Perhaps also interresting https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, however I'm sure this won't hurt. So, when you train the network on your test data, your test data should be the same dimensions. This is because otherwise, your weights which are trained in each layer won't converge to an optimum value (well, technically they would, but it would take a long time), and your network won't train properly.

My suggestion to you would be to read in the test data, and then resize each image so that they are the same size. That way, your network will train a lot faster.